# S&P 500 eps calculation

Tags: calculation

I am trying to calculate the eps for S&P 500 in order to validate the data I parsed (I got eps for 430 companies Q3 2022 year). I used different sources: seeking alpha API (is not connected with seeking alpha), marketwatch and FMP (financial modeling prep). Eventually, when I was calculating eps for S&P 500 using Shares Outstanding to find earning and divisor that I took from Ychart I got values much higher than the real S&P 500 eps. The real one is ~44, while I had about 55-60 differ from the source I used.
May be there is an issue in my calculation. I used yfinance library in Python to divide market cap of the company by its last price on the market to find SO. After multiple the value by the eps for the certain company. Sum all the values, divided by divisor (8399) and 1 mil.
I checked the eps for companies randomly and found out that eps I received is usually greater than the real values on seeking alpha or finance yahoo.
If you know a great website that could be parsed with the eps data for companies in S&P 500 list or an API or find an issue in my research steps or got the same problem and somehow overcome it, please, write an answer for my question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why 430 companies? What EPS (trailing?). Why would you want to do it yourself?

Comment: @AKdemy
I was calculating quarterly eps, not TTM. 430 companies is because not all companies begin their financial year at January, so that quarter may differ on the website. If my results would match the real values of eps S&P 500, I could take forward eps from website and get forward eps for S&P500.